# Sending Apps for Testing - Enterprise Account

Tags: ios

I have an enterprise account. I can test apps on my device from XCode. How do I send apps to other people to test?

I believe TestFlight is not available for enterprise accounts. A long time ago, ipa files used to be the way to go. With ITunes being replaced by the Music app on the Mac, the ipa file route no longer seems possible.

I couldn't find any information either on Stack Overflow or on Apple's documentations. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You can send them the enterprise signed IPA and they can drag and drop it to their device in finder. The other easy way is to put your ipa and manifest on a web server and then create a page with the install link

Answer (score 0):

You can use over-the-air installation, by uploading the ipa and Manifest.plist to a server and letting the users install the app using an install link like `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=Manifest.plist` . (See [this tutorial](https://www.impigertech.com/resources/blogs/ios-ota-app-distribution-guide) for example.)

But it's probably easier to use a 3rd party deployment service instead, like Bitwise, HockeyApp, Firebase, etc.